# Mean Absolute Error Cost Function in Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, mae

Is there any reasons **not** to use MAE as cost function in logistic regression?
Yes, I know about problems with optimization, I know that this estimation won't be max-likelihood estimation.
But is there something else? Another pitfalls?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how this could give unexpected results if you are using logistic regression for *prediction*. Suppose there is actually nothing to model, just a straightforward binomial distribution with $p=0.3$. We can predict anything between $0\leq\hat{p}\leq 1$. What will the expected MAE and MSE for various $\hat{p}$ look like? Let's simulate 1000 draws.

```
set.seed(1)
gold.standard <- runif(1e3)<0.3
summary(gold.standard)

   Mode   FALSE    TRUE 
logical     707     293

Prediction <- seq(0,1,by=0.01)
MAE <- sapply(Prediction, function(xx)mean(abs(xx-gold.standard)))
MSE <- sapply(Prediction, function(xx)mean((xx-gold.standard)^2))

plot(Prediction,MAE,ylim=range(c(MAE,MSE)),type="l",col="red",ylab="Error",lwd=2)
lines(Prediction,MSE,lwd=2)
legend("topleft",inset=.02,lwd=2,col=c("red","black"),legend=c("MAE","MSE"))
```

[image: MAE vs MSE]

The expected MSE is minimized, as expected, by $\hat{p}=p$. (More precisely, by $\hat{p}=0.293$ because of our simulation.) But the expected MAE is minimized by $\hat{p}=0$, i.e., by *always* predicting the most common outcome, FALSE. This may be what you want, but it typically isn't. (And one would usually argue that if you want a *classification* prediction, then you should really aim at getting an unbiased $\hat{p}$, then base your classification on whether $\hat{p}$ exceeds a threshold that balances the cost of Type I and II errors - not bias $\hat{p}$ itself.)

The key thing you should keep in mind is that minimizing the MAE will bias your predictions towards the *median* of their distribution (whereas minimizing the MSE will asymptotically yield unbiased predictions: you'll get their expectation). See, e.g.,  [Hanley et al., 2001, *The American Statistician*](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/000313001750358482).

An analogous problem plagues forecasts of low volume count data - if you assess your forecast quality using the MAE, you'll get "optimal" forecasts that may be a flat zero. I have written a little paper on this [(Kolassa, 2016, *IJF*)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169207016000315) which may have some helpful pointers to further literature and in fact contains an analogue to the graph above.